# Presented modal navigationcontroller under current navigationcontroller iphone

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

In my application the modal navigationcontroller that I am presenting is going under the current navigationcontroller so I'm not able to view the new navigationbar as it's disappearing under the current one.

I'm presenting the modalview on self and not self.navigationcontroller because self.navigationcontroller doesn't present the modalviewcontroller.

Also how to push a view on this modal navigationcontroller?

I'm using following code in one of my viewControllers:

```
fullListTopCompanies *fullListTopCompaniesInstance = [[fullListTopCompanies alloc] initWithNibName:@"fullListTopCompanies" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]

                                                initWithRootViewController:fullListTopCompaniesInstance];

fullListTopCompaniesInstance.navigationController.navigationItem.title = @"F";
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];


[navigationController release];

[fullListTopCompaniesInstance release];
```

Can anybody please help?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use animated with transition

according to me  you have to change the animation style

i done it before but forgot the code i will post it when i get it

Comment: GhostRider, Thanx for your reply. But changing the transition style hasn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.title = @"F";
```

Add the above line of code in viewDidLoad method of "fullListTopCompanies" class.

Answer (score -1):

Actually your navigation bar hides because of the modal view and modal view by default doesnt have Navigation bar.To add a navigation bar to modal view you can try the below code:

***In Header File***

IBOutlet fullListTopCompanies *fullListTopCompaniesInstance;

***In Implementation File***

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"fullListTopCompanies" bundle:nil];

[self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];

[nav release];

Also on the "fullListTopCompanies" View Controller dont forget to put a left navigation bar button item for dismissing the modal view.

So add that left bar button (**Ideally Cancel Button on navigation bar**) and event handler for that left barr button should contain the code

**[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];**

Hope this helps.